# Send envelope by email and generate embedded url

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate

I have a Power Automate workflow to create envelope using template, update recipients and send envelope.
After the envelope has been sent, a notification will be sent to the mail.
However, I want to also generate a link to this envelope for the recipient so that I can paste it on my site.
To do this, I tried adding a "Generate embedded signing URL" action at the end.
But after that, notifications stopped coming to the mail.
As I later found out, by default, you cannot send a notification to the mail and generate a link at the same time.
But we can add an additional property EmbeddedRecipientStartURL = "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN", which supposedly should solve this problem.

Can you please tell me how can I set this property in the actions in Power Automate?
Or I will have to create an HTTP request.
If it's possible, help me what kind of request it will be?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are using the "out of the box" connector, correct?

Comment: Yes, I use OOTB docusign connector

Comment: The OOTB connector does not offer all functionality available via the DocuSign signature REST API. You may need to build a custom connector

Comment: Ok. Maybe you can help, how to build this custom connectors. Probably, I have to use HTTP connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build a custom connector to the [DocuSign eSignature REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/).

You will need to generate an Integration Key (IK) for authentication, as you'll be using your own auth flow, so you first have to do this in the [development environment](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/account/).

Here is a step-by-step guide showing you how to do that:

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/expanding-power-automate-series-create-custom-docusign-connect-flow

You

Answer (score 2):

Here is a guide for creating a custom connector. From here you can create operations, which are essentially REST API calls with all the properties you need like embeddedrecipientstarturl

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/get-the-flow-sending-docusign-envelopes-microsoft-power-automate